# Restoring Windows FileExplorer as default for folder association. | Win10 |

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, file-association

I started using **Q-dir** parallel to the inbuilt **Windows10 FileExplorer**.
Even though I like it much for project focused file management, 
I made a move that I regretted by now and cannot revert for some reason:

It has an option to "**associate with folder links**"
After setting that, even if I open FE with Win+E hotkey for a quick interaction, 
when clicking on any folder within FE it opens up Q-dir automatically.

I have unticked the option since then in Q-dir, but that did not restore the original way.
I have looked around under File assotiations and program defaults to restore it manually, but the problem is that:

- Folders are not listed under **file type assotiations**.
- File Explorer itself has only these **protocol assotiations** available.:  'Burn to Disc' / 'Erase Disc' / 'Zipselection' / 'Search'

Does anybody know, what **registry key** should be edited to what value 
or if there is a simpler solution that I did not recognise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `regedit` and navigate to the the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\`.
Check for a sub-key whose name is similar to `Q-dir` and delete it,
then reboot.

If this does not solve the problem, verify also that the item `(default)`
is empty in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell`.

Comment: Why did you type the same path at the end 2 times? Is there maybe a 3rd that you wanted to reference? "empty in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell and HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell"  -The first 2 was enough to solve it though.... So either correct the 3rd path you provided or its also fine to remove from the solution!

Comment: You are right - deleted.